# Move right div inside flex to the right end which is inside ag-grid

Tags: css, reactjs, less, ag-grid, styling

> Im working on reactjs web app which has an ag-grid, where in a row has
> a flex div within which there are 2 div's, the first div is correctly
> placed, but I m unable to move the 2nd div to the right end within the
> grid.

```
<div className={classNames(styles.Home)>
   <div className={classNames(styles.Home__leftWrap>left column</div>
   <div className={classNames(styles.Home__rightWrap>right column</div>
</div>

.Home
  display : flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 height: 30px;
 align-items:center;

 &_leftWrap {
  width: 150px;
 }
 &_rightWrap {
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: auto;
 }  
}
```

Comment: maybe stupid question, but does your home has width at full size of screen?

Comment: I second @DimaMalko, parent container `.Home` should have some width set.

Comment: this .Home is in within ag grid colspan 5,